# jquery, how to add 2 different variables for the same call?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, indexing

i have 2 different tabs setup on the page: tabs1 and tabs2
i have this set up:

```
$( '#tabs1' ).tabs({
 select: function(event, ui) { 
var theSelectedTab = ui.index;

if (theSelectedTab  == 0) {
..do something
}
});
```

what i want to do is to add another var for the same ui.index"

```
$( '#tabs2' ).tabs({
 select: function(event, ui) { 
var theSelectedTab1 = ui.index;

if (theSelectedTab1  == 0) {
..do something
}
});
```

but it looks like `var theSelectedTab = ui.index;` is conflicting with `var theSelectedTab1 = ui.index;`

how can i separate them?

thanks

Comment: they are local variables of two different functions, and don't even have the same. I don't see how they could conflict. What problem do you have?

Comment: i was thinking the same but when i add the second var the script stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected your code and you can find the complete solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ngetw/

I think that the error comes from a missing bracket (`}`) that should close the `select: function(event, ui) {` line.

Regards.

Comment: thanks, looks like i am blind..:) how can u make the second tab from both main tabs to be active when u run the script?

Comment: @Patrioticcow: Because it's not active?